# OpenLayers map with two layers from two different sources zoom differently. Can OpenLayers change how zoom levels behave?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, arcgis

In our application we are using OpenLayers.js version 3.20.
We have a customizable setup, so that the application can show a map consisting of a number of layers from multiple sources.

Now, in a specific customer setup, we have a map layer containing houses and buildings, and another layer containing roads and some other infrastructure.
Both these layers are served from ArcGIS, but from two different servers, and two different URLs.

This is an image illustrating the problem:
[image: Roads very wide, houses stay normal]

It does not matter whether I choose to create the layers using

```
function createTiledLayer(url, params, projection, name) {
    return new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileArcGISRest({
            url: url,
            projection: projection,
            params: params
        }),
        name: name
    });
```

}

or

```
function createImageLayer(url, params, projection, name) {
    return new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageArcGISRest({
            ratio: 1,
            params: params,
            url: url,
            projection: projection
        }),
        name: name
    });
}
```

The created layers are composed with as a `layers` array, like this, coming from two different map services (`OnshoreBaseMapUrl` and `OnshorOperationalMapUrl`) and the `layerCreateFunction` is one of those two functions shown above:

```
  layers: [
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl,{ 'LAYERS': 'show:7' },primaryMapSetup.projection,'Country Coast Polygon'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl,{ 'LAYERS': 'show:6' },primaryMapSetup.projection,'Onshore Bounderies'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl,{ 'LAYERS': 'show:5' },primaryMapSetup.projection,'Field Sectors Devider poly'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:4' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Field Sector Devider'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:3' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Land Marks'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:2' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Road Tracks'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:1' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Major Roads'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreBaseMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:0' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Roads'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreOperationalMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:2' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Pipeline Station Complex'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreOperationalMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:1' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'GW Monitoring Well'),
        primaryMapSetup.layerCreateFunction(OnshoreOperationalMapUrl, { 'LAYERS': 'show:0' },primaryMapSetup.projection, 'Wells')
        ],
```

We're using the built-in zooming functionality of OpenLayers, so we do not do anything fancy when it comes to loading layers or zooming.

My hunch is that this is something to do with the setup of the resource on the ArcGIS side of things.

I'm looking for clues on how to solve this, having searched through the API and Googled for similar problems, and found nothing so far.

As the code samples above show, we pass on parameters to the ArcGIS server as part of the REST request to single out particular layers inside a map source, but can that also be used to override scales for the maps?

Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does you're projection match the tiled layer?

Comment: We were just looking into that, and have made changes to the code to always specify the correct projection. I will update here if tests show that problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was on the ArcGIS Server side! The code at the client side (including OpenLayers) had nothing to do with it.
I was not involved in fixing it, so I cannot provide details but I have been told that this *could have* been caused by differences in reference scales at the map services.